# Does the Oxford comma exist in French? / Virgule et énumération

Tags: usage, ponctuation, énumération

The comma I'm asking about is the one before the last item in a list (surrounded by '☞ ☜' in the following):

> Il habite avec Paul, Aloysius **☞ , ☜** et Éléonore.

In English, this comma is known as the [Oxford comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list); whether you use it or not is a matter of taste or, if you write for a commercial editor, of the publisher’s style guide.

The question is: in French, is this comma used? Is it mandatory, is it “forbidden” or unusual, is it a matter of style or of regional customs?

---

En anglais, une virgule peut être placée avant le dernier élément d'une liste, comme dans :

> Il habite avec Paul, Aloysius **☞ , ☜** et Éléonore.

Cela s'appelle [*Oxford comma* (la virgule d’Oxford)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list), parce qu'elle est notamment utilisée par l'éditeur *Oxford University Press*.

Ma question est : quels sont les usages de cette virgule en français ? J'ai trouvé plusieurs liens web (Wikipedia entre autres) qui varient sur la question, allant de « cela contredit les règles de la ponctuation » à « c'est une question de style au choix de l'auteur ».

Comment: Mon propre usage : je la mets lorsque je trouve qu'elle augmente la lisibilité. Notamment, dès que mes phrases sont un peu longues (j'ai un style assez verbeux, malheureusement), je la mets.

Comment: @Dave excellente modification, merci!

Comment: de rien! La force de l'UTF-8 et du système d'entrée des caractères japonais ;-)

Comment: Je croyais que la nuance en anglais entre « X, Y and Z » et « X, Y, and Z » était que dans le premier cas on a deux groupes dont un composé, dans le second trois groupes. Malheureusement l'usage n'est déjà pas assez répandu pour conclure quelque chose de certain de la première forme, surtout si la seconde est absente du document. J'ai pas de manuels de style français sous la main pour voir ce qu'il en est.

Comment: Pas de mention à l'entrée virgule dans [Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/vehicule-voie_espace_public.html) qui pourtant parle de l'espace d'un point qu'on mettait jadis avant la virgule.

Comment: @Un francophone: non, en anglais les deux sont équivalents, sauf bien sûr si tu as « X, Y and Z, W, Q »…

Comment: @F'x ça me semble dans la ligne des ambiguïtés évitées citées dans Wikipedia (qui en effet sont plus nombreuses que je le pensais).  J'ai découverts ce sujet lors d'une discussion sur un texte normatif; le bon sens a fini par prévaloir: on a changé la formulation pour ne pas en dépendre.  En effet si cet usage de la virgule peut résoudre vers un des cas d'une ambiguïté, il ne peut pas résoudre vers l'autre sauf à être d'une consistance inhumaine.

Comment: Il y a deux types d'usage de la virgule sérielle ("Oxford comma"): celui qui lève une ambiguité ("Eat, shoots, and leaves") et celui qui est juste un choix stylistique (suivant les recommandations d'Oxford University Press, par exemple).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Grevisse à la rescousse :

> La virgule sépare d'habitude les éléments coordonnés quand ils sont au nombre de trois au moins et que la conjonction *et*, *ou*, *ni* est utilisée devant plusieurs éléments :
>
> > *La terre était belle, et riche, et féconde* (Lamennais, *Paroles d'un croyant*, III). […]
>
> Quand *et* et *ou* ne se trouvent que devant le dernier terme (ce qui est le tour ordinaire), on ne met pas de virgule habituellement, quel que soit le nombre de termes :
>
> > *Une manière commode de faire la connaissance d'une ville est de chercher comment on y travaille, comment on y aime, comment on y meurt* (A. Camus, *Peste*, p. 14) […]
>
> Cependant, la virgule est utilisée si le dernier terme est précédé d'une pause, ce qui arrive notamment :
>
> - quand on veut le mettre en évidence ;
> - pour la clarté, quand les termes coordonnés sont longs et complexes ;
> - quand leur construction est fort dissemblable (par ex. si ce sont des phrases à sujets différents ou à modes différents) ;
> - quand le dernier élément contient un terme qui lui est propre (et qui, sans la virgule, serait rapporté aussi aux autres éléments) ;
> - quand il y a plusieurs coordinations distinctes ;

Answer (score 9):

On place généralement une virgule entre les éléments coordonnés par une autre conjonction que **et, ou, ni**.

> Je me suis arrêté de fumer, car ma santé en pâtissait.

On place parfois une virgule avant **et, ou, ni** si les éléments coordonnés ont un sujet différent

> Le tigre bondit, et sa patte fouette l'air

ou si la conjonction est répétée.

> Il était riche, et beau, et généreux.
>
> On pouvait parfois voir une lumière, ou une ombre vague, ou une forme de montagne.

Source : http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/U_VIRG.htm

Comment: **This link can help you** : http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/sub_autres_liens.htm different level for learning French

Answer (score 4):

Il faut également envisager le cas où, dans une énumération à trois éléments comportant deux "et", deux seulement de ces trois éléments sont liés sémantiquement. Dans ce cas, il semble logique de placer la virgule uniquement devant le second "et".

Exemple : "Il était grand et mince, et père de deux enfants".

Ici, "grand" et "mince" sont liés sans virgule par "et" puisqu'ils participent tous deux de la description physique de l'intéressé, tandis que "père de deux enfants" relève de sa situation familiale.

Notons que dans "Il était grand, et mince, et père de deux enfants", l'accent semblerait délibérément mis sur "mince". On pourrait par exemple imaginer l'emploi de cette tournure en réponse à "Il était grand et gros, et père de deux enfants". La pause créée par la virgule précédant "et mince" opposerait alors "mince" à "gros".