# Enumération : Virgules, "et"

Tags: syntaxe, énumération

Je me pose une question sur l'écriture des énumérations contenant un "et".

Je veux écrire qu'il y a trois étapes pour utiliser un ordinateur :

1. "allumer l'écran"
2. "brancher le clavier et la souris"
3. "appuyer sur l'interrupteur"

Comment bien écrire cette phrase avec des virgules ?

> Il faut allumer l'écran, brancher le clavier et la souris et appuyer sur l'interrupteur.

ou

> Il faut allumer l'écran, brancher le clavier et la souris, et appuyer sur l'interrupteur.

Pour faire la séparation à l'oral, on rajoute une pause entre "souris" et "et".

Existe t'il une belle façon d'écrire que "brancher le clavier ET la souris" et "appuyer sur l'interrupteur" sont deux étapes et non trois" ? (le branchement est une seule étape).

Comment: Voir [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/866/79) : « quand il y a plusieurs coordinations distinctes ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, je me demandais malgré tout (et malgré avoir lu la réponse de l'autre question) si les deux phrases sont acceptés grammaticalement.. Soit : "*[...],[] et [], et []*" et "*[...],[] et [] et []*". Ou s'il n'y a qu'une seule des deux qui soit correcte grammaticalement? C'est encore nébuleux..