# Après une énumération faut-il une virgule avant « voire » qui la termine ?

Tags: ponctuation, énumération

> 1a - Peut-être est-il à Londres, à Oxford voire à Dublin.
>
> 1b - La valeur prend 10, 12, 13 voire 14 dans les cas extrêmes !
>
> ---
>
> 2a - Peut-être est-il à Londres, à Oxford, voire à Dublin.
>
> 2b - La valeur prend 10, 12, 13, voire 14 dans les cas extrêmes !

Ayant l'habitude de mettre une `,` après la pénultième énumération précédent *voire*, comme dans les cas 2a et 2b, je me demande si sa suppression est une faute typographique, une liberté[,] voire une mauvaise habitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my interpretation of my “Le Robert-Micro,” “voire” is a reinforcing adverb used to coordinate ONE assertion or ONE idea by linking it to a single second, usually more drastic assertion (and according to the [Office Québécois de la langue français](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3452), “voire” is usually preceded by a comma).

For the sake of logic, it would seem (to me, at least) that the two assertions/ideas linked by “voire” cannot be totally mutually exclusive (the French definition/synonym is “ET même” and not “ET/OU même”), and therefore its use in a list of multiple, totally mutually exclusive options (as in your two examples) sounds awkward to me (one can’t be in all three cities at the same time and something can’t be worth all 4 values simultaneously) and I would suggest using “ou même,” as a conjunction without a comma before “ou” (“et même,” par contre would need a comma, but only when it is clearly being used, like “voire,” as a coordinating/reinforcing adverb and not merely as a conjunction followed by “même”).

To use “voire” in a way that doesn’t sound awkward to me in your examples, I would say:

Peut-être est-il dans une ville anglophone, voire à Dublin.

and

La valeur dépasse 9, voire 14 dans les cas extrêmes !

Answer (score 4):

*Voire* est un adverbe, pas une conjonction donc il n'y a pas d'analogie à faire avec [ce qui se fait pour les conjonctions *et*, *ou* et *ni*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/830/176). Je ferais donc ce qui se fait systématiquement quand il y a une énumération dont le dernier terme n'est pas introduit par une conjonction, mettre une virgule pour le séparer du terme précédant (ce qui est l'usage dans les exemples du TLFi et du dictionnaire de l'Académie).

Answer (score 0):

Je pencherai pour la 1a et 1b.
De manière générale, la dernière énumération n'a pas de virgule la précédant.

```
Peut-être est-il à Londres, à Oxford ou à Dublin.
```

Cependant, c'est quelque chose que l'on voit souvent, et je ne pense pas que ce soit une faute que de la mettre.

Je pense donc que c'est une liberté, à vérifier cependant.