# “Ou” before the last item in a list

Tags: conjonctions, énumération

Sometimes items that are mutually inclusive are nevertheless joined by “ou” instead of “et”.

> Reconnu et acclamé par ses pairs et aînés que sont David Bowie, Tom Waits, Kurt Cobain, Eddie Vedder ou Matt Groening ... ([source](http://www.camionblanc.com/detail-livre-sorry-entertainer-la-production-artistique-de-daniel-johnston-de-1979-a-1986-1127.php))

In English, I'd expect “and”. True, “or” can complete the construction “such as”, and a translator might even use that here, but syntactically the French seems to function differently from “tels que”.

There is some overlap with [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/528/comment-indiquer-quun-ou-est-inclusif/536#536), and the accepted answer's claim that French uses “ou” by default for inclusivity could be the key, but that answer doesn't seem very popular. Is it correct? Meanwhile, “et” is present in many of the lists where you'd expect it in [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/830/does-the-oxford-comma-exist-in-french-virgule-et-%C3%A9num%C3%A9ration).

Some questions (feel free to avoid responding point by point):

1. How common is this? Does it suggest a particular style or register?
2. Is it only used in lists that could mean something like “such as”? If not, where else?
3. Would “et” sound strange here? For example, would “et” suggest that the list is exhaustive?

Comment: Using *ou* here suggests the author is picking people as examples from a longer list. *Et* would imply the enumeration contains all the possible peers and elders of the person being talked about, as you surmised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *How common is this? Does it suggest a particular style or register?*

  It is a very common use of “ou” in a list. No particular register, just to express the fact that you can choose between the elements of the list.
- *Is it only used in lists that could mean something like “such as”? If not, where else?*

  Not like “such as”, more like “One way **or** another”, not used to compare but to give another choice.
- *Would “et” sound strange here? For example, would “et” suggest that the list is exhaustive?*

  If you used “et” here, you would suggest that every element of the list is part of the same group.
  Exemples : *Clever, cool **and** big are adjectives.* *You can pick clever, cool **or** big to describe something or someone*.
  “Et” would not sound strange, it would change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, though I don't think it addresses exactly the same issue I'm raising. In the example sentence and other lists like it, there's no reason to choose between the people; they're all the musician's peers and elders.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Have you considered Groening is the only non-musician in the list? With the typical construction the coordination appears before the last item in the list. What if something was missing because of an _ellipse_ of sth. which was maybe equivalent to something like _or still even_ in English (but this is beyond my level of proficiency and the scope of the site)? I'm not sure about the missing word I would add to _ou_ here. But then you could have an addition by way of a nuance about the profession, within an list of items linked by an incl. or which would indeed be non-finite imho...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Some mix of "ou même", "ou aussi", "ou encore"? Not sure it's the most probable or reasonable interpretation but Groening's difference in this written list sort of enables a walking back of the garden path so to speak. Thanks.

Comment: Very good point. "Like these musicians, or artist Matt Groening," that is. ("ou bien" is another option to add to your list.) I agree that could influence this case, though now I have to keep my eyes peeled, because I've seen this elsewhere and would need to see whether that caveat applies to the other cases.